# 8GB model iPhone 4S is only showing 5.4GB capacity (4.2GB available)

Tags: iphone, storage

It used to say 8GB capacity in the General > About Settings menu. Now it only says 5.4. I've done a "restore as new" but it's still showing the same.

Help?

[image]

Comment: On my 64 GB it displays a capacity of 56.6 GB so I assume this is the iOS using that space and the file system itself ( but 7.4 GB is a lot).

Comment: I my case total useable space is 2300 MB 8 gb space 5 gb available and after os space it left with 2.3 gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system (OS: iOS 8.x) is using up space as well and you're not able to use this space. The phone comes with 8GB, yes, but minus the space used for the OS. I think Apple got into problems when they advertised with 8GB/16GB etc. while people could only effectively use that space MINUS the space used by the OS.

Comment: well it's true that the OS is taking up the space, but I don't think Apple is special about that or even got in trouble, it's standard in the industry to state capacity with OS, also they still sell 8 GB of storage .

Comment: Oh, it's definitely an industry standard, but it is odd imo. It's like advertising a 12oz can of soda, neglecting to mention that 2oz are reserved for future use. Just seems a bit odd.

Comment: A pair of Florida men sued Apple for it. Not sure about the outcome though. Source: http://www.computerworld.com/article/2864230/iphone-owners-sue-apple-over-storage-space-allege-fraud.html